# How do I call an http function from pubsub.schedule

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have the following code:

```
exports.warmFunctions = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun((context) => {
   //call http.onCall teste2
})

exports.teste2 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   console.log(''+data)
})
```

Is there any way to call the 'test2' function from pubsub.schedule? Any help I appreciate

Comment: You can call any function in your code but it would be your responsibility to pass in the parameters of the correct format/nature.  For example, you should be able to call exports.test2(...) from within your ...schedule() body.   I'd probably factor out function of your test2() from its HTTP wrapper.

Comment: In my case it has to be via http, because the system I'm doing is to heat the http function

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the function according to the specification for callable functions that you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).  There are no provided libraries for callable functions for nodejs, so you will have to write something yourself using what you see in the linked documentation.  It is just an HTTP function with additional protocol surrounding it.

Comment: Through my research, I saw that it has dependencies like express app and firebase / app, is it possible to use in nodejs?

Comment: You can certainly give it a try, but it's not designed to work there.

Comment: OK thank you. Just to clarify, do you know any example for heating http functions? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: If you're looking for example code, I suggest doing web searches.

Comment: I get the sense that this might be useful ... https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

From here, you can call your function using REST API exposed by AXIOS.  Not yet clear why you don't call the function from outside the function?  eg from CURL from an external machine?

Comment: You can invoke the deployed function any way you want.

Comment: In my research on functional heating, I found it to be a very efficient form of heating functions using crontab. I'm using pubsub.schedule, but I have no idea what the http function calls, a code example would help a lot